# Не записывается переменная success ajax

Tags: ajax, post

Подскажите пожалуйста, почему не записывается переменная из success ajax:

```js
function check() {
  var mail_check;
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/mail_check.php",
    data: {
    },
    success: function(html) {
      mail_check = 1;
    }
  });
  if (mail_check === 1) {
  /*code*/
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" onclick="check();" value="go">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function check() {
  var mail_check;
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    async: false,
    url: "/mail_check.php",
    data: {
    },
    success: function(html) {
      mail_check = 1;
    }
  });
  if (mail_check === 1) {
  /*code*/
  }
}
```

Comment: как я и написал, в своем ответе.

Comment: Прочитайте https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/ про `async: false`.

Answer (score 0):

Либо банально добавь в код ажакса `async: false,`, либо снизу человеческий способ

В начале(на 1 строке) файла, который с функцией

```js
const apost=(_url, _data={})=>{
    return new Promise((resolve)=>{
        $.ajax({
            url: _url,
            type: 'POST',
            data: _data,
            async: true,
        }).done((r)=>{
            if(!r)r = false;
            resolve(r);
        }).catch((e)=>{
            console.log(e.status, e.responseText, e);
            resolve(false);
        });
    });
};
```

В своей функции вызываешь:

```js
(async()=>{
    let r = await apost('/mail_check.php', {data: 'yes'});

    console.log('response', r);
})();
```

асинхронная функция выглядит\создается так:

```js
const func_name=async()=>{ /* code */ };
```